# Is a normalized cosine similarity a Bregman divergence?

Tags: inner-products, euclidean-domain

A Bregman divergence is defined as
$D(p,q) = F(p) - F(q) - < \nabla F(q), p-q>$
with F a strictly convex function of the Legendre type.

Squared Euclidian distance is a Bregman divergence, with $F(x)= ||x||^2$.

For a Cosine Distance we can show it is proportional to the squared Euclidian distance:
$||p - q||^2 = ||p||^2 + ||q||^2 - 2 cos(p,q)$
which becomes 
$2 - 2 p^T q$
when normalizing $||p||=||q||=1$.

Does this imply the normalized Cosine similarity is also a Bregman divergence?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).